# How do I add another attribute to style in a view file (macro) in apostrophe CMS?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

So I have a code that's like this:

```
  <a {% if options.style %} style="{{ options.style }}" {% endif %} href="{{ path }}">some text</a>
```

Now I want to add an additional property tp style, say for `padding` that's coming from another attribute. How can I do that?

I tried this way but it didn't work.

```
<a {% if options.style %} style=" {{ {...options.style, padding: {{data.linkPadding}}} }}" {% endif %}>some Text</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is nunjucks (it doesn't work like just extending javascript object as I was trying to do), the way to do this would be following:

```
<a
     {% if options.style %} 
        style="{{ options.style }}; 
                 padding: {{data.linkPadding}}"
     {% endif %}>some Text</a>
```

This was answered by
[Bob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19515646/bob-means) on apostrophe Discord community.

Comment: A closing " is required to end the style attribute.

Comment: @TomBoutell Thanks for catching it. Done

Comment: Hmm, not to be a pain, but your new close-quote is outside the endif, so it will appear even if there is no style attribute.

Comment: Not at all. Thanks for noticing it. Done